# How can I obtain values of key-value pair from a Hashmap?

Tags: java

```
mylogger.info("original request start: "+request.getQueryString());
System.out.println("Query1:" + request.getQueryString());
QueryStats queryStats=new QueryStats();
Map parameterMap = request.getParameterMap()==null? null:new HashMap(request.getParameterMap());
System.out.println("Query2:" + parameterMap);

Collection newParamsValue=parameterMap.values();
Object newParams[]=newParamsValue.toArray();
StringBuffer strParam=new StringBuffer() ;
int l=newParams.length;
for(int i=0;i<l;i++){
    **strParam=strParam.append((StringBuffer)newParams[i]);**
}
```

I want to get all the values into a string. How can I get it?

Comment: May be you want to parse `newParams[i]` into `String` rather than `StringBuffer`.

Comment: Writing Java code in a JSP file instead of a Java class doesn't make it a JSP problem. I replaced the JSP tag by Java tag.

Answer (score 1):

The [parameter map](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getParameterMap%28%29) is a `Map<String, String[]>`.  The proposed `Object[]#toString()` answers will not work at all. You need to loop over the `String[]` as well. Also, you have to URL-encode the key-value pairs in order to create a proper HTTP query string. Here's how it should be done:

```
public static String toQueryString(Map<String, String[]> params) {
    StringBuilder queryString = new StringBuilder();

    for (Entry<String, String[]> param : params.entrySet()) {
        for (String value : param.getValue()) {
            if (queryString.length() > 0) {
                queryString.append("&amp;");
            }

            queryString
                .append(URLEncoder.encode(param.getKey(), "UTF-8"))
                .append("=")
                .append(URLEncoder.encode(value, "UTF-8"));
        }
    }

    return queryString.toString();
}
```

Use this as follows

```
Map<String, String[]> params = request.getParameterMap();
String queryString = toQueryString(params);
// ...
```

Answer (score 0):

use StringBuilder:

```
 StringBuilder sb = new StringBuidler();

for(int i=0;i<l;i++){
    sb.append(newParams[i].toString());
}
```

Comment: This answer is invalid. The parameter value is a `String[]`. The `toString()` will return a completely different value than you'd expect.

Answer (score 0):

a slight variation on previous suggestion:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

for (Object o : parameterMap.values()) {
   String[] parameterValues = (String[]) o;
   for ( String parameterValue : parameterValues) {
       sb.add(parameterValue);
   }

}
```

Comment: Notice that the for-each structure only works from J2SE_1.5. Before this release only is possible do a for-each loop with the basic for structure

Comment: This answer is invalid. The parameter value is a `String[]`. The `toString()` will return a completely different value than you'd expect.

Comment: @TheCharliemops: you are correct, but FYI JDK 5 was released in 2004! So one would assume that it's widely used and there wasn't anything to the contrary in OP.

Comment: Each of the entry value is a `String[]`. See also [parameter map javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getParameterMap%28%29). This will only result in the `Object[]#toString()` been added like `Ljava.lang.String;@1d66aa9`. See also the OP's complaint in the follow-up question which s/he incorrectly opened: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7176385/how-to-create-query-from-hashmap

Comment: You are correct Balus, I've edited the answer to reflect your corrections.

Comment: @Ashkan Aryan I also think it's widely used, but I have done the comment because maybe someone try it in older versions and found problems. About the warning made by @BalusC, it's also fixed replacing the line `String[] parameterValues = (String[]) o;` with the following line `String[] parameterValues = o.toArray(new String[o.size]);`