# How to create query from HashMap?

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I obtain values of key-value pair from a Hashmap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7174987/how-can-i-obtain-values-of-key-value-pair-from-a-hashmap)

```
QueryStats queryStats=new QueryStats();
Map parameterMap = request.getParameterMap()==null? null:new HashMap(request.getParameterMap());
System.out.println("Query2:" + parameterMap);

Collection newParamsValue=parameterMap.values();
Object newParams[]=newParamsValue.toArray();
StringBuffer strParam=new StringBuffer() ;
int l=newParams.length;
for(int i=0;i<l;i++){
    strParam=strParam.append(newParams[i].toString());
}

output: Query2:{sortPrefix=[Ljava.lang.String;@1d66aa9, searsOnly=[Ljava.lang.String;@1f4bdca, globalPrefix=[Ljava.lang.String;@d81cda, indent=[Ljava.lang.String;@4e57ba, qt=[Ljava.lang.String;@1619137, wt=[Ljava.lang.String;@84c1f9, fq=[Ljava.lang.String;@1dae27f}
```

From this parameterMap, I want to create a query? How is it possible?

Comment: You already asked this question before: [How can I obtain values of key-value pair from a Hashmap?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7174987/how-can-i-obtain-values-of-key-value-pair-from-a-hashmap). If the answers doesn't satisfy you, you should post a comment or improve your question, not to post a new one.

Comment: Err, is it really the same question? looks like a follow-up...

Comment: What kind of query? Database? BTW - `strParam` is practically unusuable because you concatenate the values *without* delimiters...

Comment: @Andreas: the other question had no correct answers at that point (but now it has one).

Comment: OK, agreed and joining in to close this question.

Comment: This is not a duplicate question: I found this question when I was trying to find a ready library method that takes a map of the form {a:b, c:d, e:f...} and generates "select * from table where a=b and c=d and e=f", or "insert into table(a, c, e) values(b, d, f)". The other question does not ask that.

Answer (score 1):

If the `request` is a HTTP request (and I suspect it is) and the query is a database query, then what you're trying to do is a big no-no. Always, always, always sanitize your input. Just stop for a moment and think with the mind of a malicious person trying to wreck or obtain your database content, trying to forge a HTTP request that fools your unsuspecting application into doing exactly that.

Another thing about HTTP request parameters is that they come in string arrays. If you want the string value of an input, you need to cast your values to `String[]` first, then grab the first element of that array. Please note that the array can be empty though, and this method only works for single value inputs, multiple selection inputs will return multiple elements.

Answer (score 1):

The problem you face is that the map returned from `getParameterMap` maps String keys to *arrays* of String values. So each element of `newParamsValue` is a `String[]`. You need to do a little more work to get a sensible (comma-separated) string out of these than calling `toString()`. Something like this (untested) might do what you want:

```
ArrayList<String> toStrings(Collection requestValues) {
    ArrayList<String> strings;
    for (Object object : requestValues) {
        String[] vals = (String[]) object;
        if (vals.length() == 1) {
            strings.add(vals[0]);
        } else if (vals.length() > 1) {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(vals[0]);
            for (int i = 1; i < vals.length(); ++i) {
                sb.append(',');
                sb.append(vals[i]);
            }
            strings.add(sb.toString());
        }
    }
    return strings;
}
```